# How to drag and drop something but it doesn't disappear so we can keep on drag and drop it

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, drag-and-drop

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  ev.target.appendChild(document.getElementById(data));
}


<div class = “container”>
  <div class = “row” >
    <div class="col-md-1 center">
      <img src="https://i.stack.imgur.com/vxnww.jpg" style="height: 250px">
    </div>
    <div class="col-md-1">
      <div class="boxFirstCol" id="div1" ondrop="drop(event)" ondragover="allowDrop(event)"> </div>
      <p><b>4s</b></p>
      <div class="box"> </div>
      <p><b>3s</b></p>
      <div class="box"> </div>
      <p><b>2s</b></p>
      <div class="box"> </div>
      <p><b>1s</b></p>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

There are more codes to make it look this way but I am able to drag and drop the electrons inside the boxes then the electrons from the box will be gone.

Comment: add css also for better visual

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this :-

```
function allowDrop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
}

function drag(ev) {
  ev.dataTransfer.setData("text", ev.target.id);
}

function drop(ev) {
  ev.preventDefault();
  var data = ev.dataTransfer.getData("text");
  var clonedElement = document.getElementById(data).cloneNode(true);
  clonedElement.id = "element_1"; // Set unique id for each element I have used static one.
  ev.target.appendChild(clonedElement);
}
```

You will have to use cloneNode(true) to clone the element.

Comment: If it works, please accept the answer. So that it will be helpful for other users.

Comment: There are 2 elements that i want to clone and both got cloned only that both id became the same when it was different originally.

Comment: I have mentioned in comment in code that you will have to change the element's id when dropped. See "// Set unique id for each element I have used static one."